# VB.NET: Populating a list in Linq

Tags: .net, vb.net, collections, linq-to-xml

Assume I have the following XML file:

```
<Movies>
     <Movie ownerName="Ryan">
          <Title>The Lord of the Rings Trilogy</Title>
          <Title>Saving Private Ryan</Title>
          <Title>etc</Title>
     </Movie>
     <Movie ownerName="Rynina">
          <Title>Foo</Title>
          <Title>Bar</Title>
     </Movie>
</Movies>
```

What I'm after is using Linq to Xml to retrieve classes of type MovieCollection. MovieCollection has two properties, OwnerName (String) and Movies (List(Of String)).

Generally, I'd do something like:

```
From entry in movies...<Movie>_
Select New MovieCollection With { _
.OwnerName = entry.@Title.Value, _
.MovieCollection = entry.<Title>.Value}
```

However in this case this obviously wont work. Is there anyway to fill the MovieCollection list with all the movies that occur for that owner using Linq?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should really name the tags `Movie` `MovieCollection` and `Title` `Movie`.

Parse your XML with:

```
Dim doc = XDocument.Parse("<xml>")
```

or

```
Dim doc = XDocument.Load("path")
```

and use this:

```
Dim movieCollections = From movieCol In doc.Root.Elements("Movie")
                       Select New MovieCollection() With
                              {
                                    .OwnerName = movieCol.Attribute("ownerName"),
                                    .Movies = movieCol.Elements("Title")
                                                      .Select(Function(m) m.Value)
                                                      .ToList()
                              }
```

Comment: You just beat me (and I was doing it in C# too)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the serialization

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316730